# labeling/ coloring elements/segments of a linnet object

Tags: spatstat

I have 3 related questions for plots in spatstat:

1. How do I label the segment of a linnet. for example just the id of the element
2. How do I label co-variate attached to segment of linnet on a plot
3. How to control width of an segment of linnet in a plot based on: a covariate or for example I want the thickness of the segment proportional to number of points realized on that segment from a point process on a network. So if a process generates 10 points on a line segment and 5 points on second segment, I would like to plot first segment twice wider than second segment.

I found examples in the book - Spatial Point Patterns - but they indicate use of image or kernel density to control the width of a segment. I am using linfun for a inhomogenous process and I did not find a method to color or control line width in my plot or to label the plot.

An example of small square:

```
library(spatstat)

v<-ppp(x=c(50,100,100,50), y=c(50,50,100,100),c(0,150), c(0,150)) #vertices
edg<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,1), ncol=2) #edges
L<-linnet(v, edges=edg) #create a linnet

z<-c(11,22,33,44) # create covariate
Zfun <- linfun(function(x,y,seg,tp) { seg }, L)

plot(Zfun)

# I added some marks
marks(x) <- runif(npoints(x), 3, 4)
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide an example of an `linnet` and the co-variate attached to the segments you talk about. Also provide a `lpp` on a small `linnet` with a different number of points. Also provide an `linfun`...

Comment: I added a small example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything by creating a suitable function of class `linfun`.

As an example, take the network `L <- simplenet`.

For question 1:

```
f <- linfun(function(x,y,seg,tp) { seg }, L)
plot(f)
```

The function `f` returns the segment ID number of the segment containing the specified point. This number runs from `1` to `nsegments(L)`.

For question 2, suppose you have a vector `Z` giving the value of a covariate for each segment of the network (assuming the covariate value is constant on each segment). I'll take the example `Z <- runif(nsegments(L))`. Then

```
 g <- linfun(function(x,y,seg,tp) { Z[seg] }, L)
 plot(g)
```

For question 3,

```
 plot(g, style="width")
```

See `help(plot.linfun)` and `help(plot.linim)` (basically `plot.linfun` converts the function to a pixel image, and then calls `plot.linim`).

Comment: Thank you. When I follow your suggestion, it makes a legend with colors and each segment is assigned a color. I was actually wanting to `label on the segments in plot itself`. I mean like a text (value of covariates, value of #of points realized or ID of the segment itself) to display along the plot segments. Would that be possible? I want to use spatstat plots rather than transferring them to any GIS package or external GIS program.

Comment: OK, then just use `S <- as.psp(L)` to convert the linear network to a list of line segments, then `M <- midpoints.psp(S)` to find the location of the midpoint of each segment, then `plot(L); text(M, labels=Z)` to plot the labels. See `?text.default` for arguments to tweak the position of the labels.

Comment: Thank you this answers all my queries in this question. :)